# Hopf algebroids without antipode

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, terminology

A cogroupoid object in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$ is called a Hopf algebroid over $R$. How are cocategory objects in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$ called? (Unfortunately, [bialgebroid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bialgebroid) is already taken, which seems to mean something else.) We can define comodules as usual; the notion of a comodule over a Hopf algebroid does not use the antipode. Is there some literature about these comodules? If we allow stacks to be fibered in non-groupoids, these comodules can probably be seen as quasi-coherent modules on the corresponding "stack".

Comment: A "cocategory of object in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$" is the "commutative case of bialgebroid" (as in the linked nlab page). In more recent literature a "cogroupoid object in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$" is the "commutative case of Hopf algebroid", while Hopf algeboid itself is a bialgebroid with an antipode https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+algebroid.

Comment: @DimitriChikhladze: Thank you, this is useful to know..

Answer (score 1):

Converting Dimitri Chikhladze's comment to an answer:

> A "cocategory of object in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$" is the "commutative case of bialgebroid" (as in the linked nlab page). In more recent literature a "cogroupoid object in $\mathsf{CAlg}_R$" is the "commutative case of Hopf algebroid", while Hopf algeboid itself is a bialgebroid with an antipode https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+algebroid.

Comment: Can you explain more why this is the commutative case of a bialgebroid? The nlab definition at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bialgebroid is quite complicated and I don't see the connection.